# Is there always a matrix $M$ for unitary matrix $U$ such that $M^k = U$ for given integer $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there always a (finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional) matrix $M$ for unitary matrix $U$ such that $M^k = U$ for given integer $k$? Would $M$ be unitary?

Comment: Do you mean *given* any $k$ there is such a matrix, or just is there a $k$? [if the latter then can use $k=1$ so probably not that option]

Comment: @coffeemath given any $k$. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

For existence, you have that $U$, being normal, is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix. This allows you to reduce the problem to the case where $U$ is diagonal, where it is trivial. The same can be done when $U$ is an operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, now requiring the Spectral Theorem.

On the opposite direction, $M$ doesn't have to be a unitary, nor there has to be a bound on $\|M\|$. For instance, 
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&n\\ 0&-1\end{bmatrix} 
$$
satisfies $M^2=I$ for any $n$.